# Print Composer Legend Issues

Tags: qgis, print-composer, legend, printing

I seem to be unable to successfully create a legend in print composer. The legend eventually appears after some time, but crashes out when I attempt to edit the titles, layers etc.  Today I have downloaded the latest version of QGIS, created all the layers and mapping from scratch but to no avail.

Comment: Please add details about the steps you are using and the type (data sources) of layers in your map. It is NOT normal that QGIS crashes on adding a legend. I do it all the time on both Windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: How many layers do you have? What format are they? Are they subdivided into many different categories?

Comment: Sorry for some reason your responses got caught in my spam folder.  I have 5 layers, comprising of 4 vectors layers (points and buffers) and one raster layer of Ordance Survey mapping data.  I can build the print layout in composer, but as soon as I add and try to edit a legend the system crashes.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: As underdark said, this is not normal behavior. It will require some troubleshooting. Try creating a new project, import only one of the layers, create a print composer and add a legend. Repeat with a new project for each layer, then try this with different combinations of layers. In this way perhaps you can figure out if one layer causes the issue.